# How do I replace a MySQL Database?

Tags: cpanel, mysql, phpmyadmin

I created a database on the host server using PHPMyAdmin.

I exported the database for local development and have since added data and changed the schema slightly.

How can I replace the database on the server with my local version? Some source I read say to go to that database in PHPMyAdmin and upload, but I'm not convinced that is correct.

How do I replace a MySQL Database?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. You just export your database as sql file and import it via phpmyadmin.

**Export:**

[image: Export database via phpmyadmin]

**Import:**

Note that if you have a very large sql file your host might not let you upload it via this wizard.

[image: Import database via phpmyadmin]

Comment: Note that this method fails, because the Export script is trying to create tables that already exist. You'll need to drop those tables from the server database first.

Comment: However, if you pick "Custom" as the _Export Method_ then you get the options to "Add DROP DATABASE statement", "Add CREATE DATABASE", "Add DROP TABLE", "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS", etc.

Answer (score 1):

There is an alternative way to export and import the database **if you have terminal access to the server**.

**Export the file via terminal**
Execute the following command replacing the MySQL username, database name, and the filename you wish to create.

```
mysqldump -u <username> -p <dbname> > <filename>.sql
```

**Import the file using terminal**
After uploading the file to your server, you can browse to the location and execute the following command replacing the MySQL username, database name, and the filename you already have.

```
mysql -u <username> -p <dbname> < <filename>.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

On your local machine you need to backup the database in .sql format. Once you do, access phpMyadmin from your cPanel. Click on the database and import the .sql file.